# Why does drop shadow work on input but not div elements?

Tags: html, css

This input element has a drop shadow:

```css
.test {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 20px 13px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.03)) drop-shadow(0 8px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.08));
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input class="test" />
```

But this div element does not:

```css
.test {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 20px 13px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.03)) drop-shadow(0 8px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.08));
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"> </div>
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Your code is working fine, it's because of background is transparent try to give the  background color to div and the drop shadow will be visible

Comment: Yeah that works; if you want to make your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code is working fine, it's because of background is transparent try to give the background color to div and the drop shadow will be visible.**

```css
.test {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 20px 13px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.03)) drop-shadow(0 8px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.08));
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```